# Why this if condition "if num is int:" doesn't work?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know this can seems silly if you are a code guru. But if you answer it, you'll be something like a code bodhisattva in the coder's supernatural realm. It's suppose to be a joke.

So, I wrote this bit of code:

```
def media():    
n = 0
soma = 0
while True:
    print("Type a number")
    num = input()
    print type(num)
    if num is int:
        soma = soma + num
        n = n + 1
        print "soma =", soma, " num = ", num, " n = ", n
        media = soma/n
        print media
    else:
        break
media()
```

When I run the code, I get something like this:

[image]

My question is: why the condition `if num is int:` is not fulfilled?

My goal is to make the condition "if the user types ENTER, then break".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, the correct syntax is "if isinstance(num, int)". Well, python is so beautifull simple and the form "if num is int:" seems to be so neat. What a pity!

Comment: Note that type-checking is generally considered bad form in Python, as is using `input()` in 2.x - use `raw_input()` instead, and then use `int()` to try and make a number from the returned string. If it succeeds, it's a number, if an exception is thrown, it isn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if isinstance(num, int)
```

Would be the correct way.

```
if num is int
```

is checking whether the identity of `num` and `int` are the same, except `int` is a type and `num` is an instance of that type so they are not the same object.